# How to hide specific page (from wp-admin) for certain users in wp?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-admin

My Image

[image]

I just wanted to hide specific page for certain users.

```
function remove_menus(){
    // get current login user's role
    $roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;
    // test role
    if( in_array('administrator',$roles)){
        remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' ); //Posts
        remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );
        remove_menu_page('edit.php');
        remove_menu_page('wpcf7');
    }
     
    }
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' , 100 );
```

This what I am tried upto now and its working fine for all the page.

> My question is I dont want to show home - Front page (Please see my image) If logged in user is not admin. and also I want to hide **add new**

Comment: Yea I don't know why that's not built into wordpress, I've used this plugin in the past but you have to add some functions for the logic you want, https://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-items-visibility-control/  I just realized I suggested a code change to it 4 years 3month ago,  Man how time flys.... lol

Comment: Let me have a look sir

Comment: Yea basically you write a function (that returns true/false), and this plugin adds a field into the menu items box (where you set the name and url) where you can put that function name as text.  It doesn't prevent direct access to the page, but it works great to hide the menu items, because it keeps the logic close to the menu item, so it's easy to add or remove a function when you change the menu around.  The issue I had with it 4 years ago is if the function doesn't exist it didn't give me a sensible error message, which made it hard to track down.  I think it uses `eval` though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment sir, But dineshkashera solution worked for me, But how can I hide the add new option for specific users.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use user's role capabilities and allow on the basis of role for add new items.

```
function manage_user_action() {

 // get current login user's role
    $roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;
    
    if( !in_array('administrator',$roles)){
        //remove capabilities 
        $roles->remove_cap( 'edit_pages');
    }
   
    
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'manage_user_action');
```

**To Remove Page from list**

```
function jp_exclude_pages_from_admin($query) {
 
   global $pagenow, $post_type;
 
  if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'page' )
    $query->query_vars['post__not_in'] = array( '10'); // Enter your page IDs here

  //don't forget to the query
   return $query;
 
}
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'jp_exclude_pages_from_admin' );
```

For more help see this link : [Click Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_cap)

Comment: Bro thanks a lot its work like a charm but have a single issue, How can i hide the add new button

Comment: Please mark as an answer , so it helps other developers too :)

Comment: You can hide the add new button using capabilities parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I have extended @dineshkashera answer to target a specific user by ID and the code should be as follows :

```
function jp_exclude_pages_from_admin($query) {

       global $pagenow, $post_type;

       $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

          if ( $current_user_id == 2 && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'page' )
            $query->query_vars['post__not_in'] = array( '11', '12','13'  ); // Enter your page IDs here

    }
    add_filter( 'parse_query', 'jp_exclude_pages_from_admin' );
```

This code will get the user with ID of 2 and remove the pages IDs 11,12 and 13 from their WP page edit screen.